# Add calculated columns to dataframe for each value in a vector

Tags: r, dplyr, apply

I have a vector `testlen <- c(4, 5, 6)` and the standard `iris` dataset.

I want to add a column to `iris` that tests the `Sepal.Length` for each element in `testlen`. If the `Sepal.Length` is longer than the element in `testlen`, then do some operation like the one below.

I only know how to do it using mutate like this:

```
iris <- iris %>% mutate(ratio1 = if_else(Sepal.Length> testlen[1], Petal.Length/Petal.Width,0)) %>%
                    mutate(ratio2 = if_else(Sepal.Length> testlen[2], Petal.Length/Petal.Width,0)) %>%
                    mutate(ratio3 = if_else(Sepal.Length> testlen[3], Petal.Length/Petal.Width,0))
```

It seems like there is some way to do it using the apply() function, but I'm not sure how.

(I don't care about the names of the new calculated columns. Anything is fine.)

Comment: Is it always the same operation? independently which element of `testlen` was shorter?

Comment: Always the same operation, but done for different values of Sepal.Length which is what the ```testlen``` vector is for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cbind(iris, with(iris, setNames(lapply(testlen, function(x){
    (Sepal.Length > x) * Petal.Length/Petal.Width
}), seq_along(testlen))))
```

OR

```
calc = with(iris, data.frame(sapply(testlen, "<", Sepal.Length) * Petal.Length/Petal.Width))
cbind(iris, calc)
```